# Aggregate over repeated fields: BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am new to bigquery and trying to understand how to aggregate over nested array.

The data fields looks something like this

```
clientid region  m.metric  m.metric.key  m.metric.value
     1      A.     large       0            100
                              10            200
                              20            300
```

How can I get the aggregate of the metric.values grouped on clientid

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try the following solution:

```
with sample as (
    select 1 as clientid, "A." as region, STRUCT("large" as metric, struct([0,10,20] as key, [100,200,300] as value) as x) as m
)
select clientid
, sum(metric_value)
from sample
cross join unnest(m.x.value) as metric_value
group by clientid
```

Comment: How can I adopt this solution if there are large number of m.metric.key and m.metric.value records. Instead of struct[10,20,30] Is there a way to generalize this?